# Get sticky post from category?

Tags: categories, sticky-post

I have parent category is Game `cat_id=42`. Child categories are : acrade, causual,....
I want show a top game module in mainpage template, it will show 10 sticky post from game category.

This my code :

```
<?php 
   $args = array(
      'cat' => 42,
      'posts_per_page' => 10,
      'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
   );
   query_posts( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code in the mainpage template to show the sticky posts.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'cat'            => 42,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__in'       => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
```

The above will print the title of the sticky posts